# Redirecting after signout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

When I sign out, my navigation doesn't change to reflect that I'm signed out until I refresh the page.

I set it up like this:

```
<%- if !user_signed_in? %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Sign up", new_registration_path(:user) %><br />
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to "Sign in", new_user_session_path %><br />
    </li>
<% else -%>
    <li>
        <%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path(:user), :method => :delete %>


    </li>
<% end -%>
```

My routes.rb is pretty simple:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
  root 'home#index'
end
```

And the destroy function looks like this:

```
  def destroy
    super
  end

  private

  # Overwriting the sign_out redirect path method
  def after_sign_out_path_for(user)
    root_path
  end
```

Comment: Under your `destroy` function, try adding `redirect_to root_path` and see if that does it.

Comment: I'm getting this error: Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".

Comment: I removed the after_sign_out_path_for but that didn't help either

Comment: That's because you are trying to call redirect twice. You can just remove your destroy method since it's just calling super anyway. Make sure that your `after_sign_out_path_for` is in your ApplicationController